# Solve laplace equation for a semi-infinite plate. Where is my mistake?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The plate is semi-infinite. 2 Of its sides have $f=0$ and the bottom part satisfies $f=cos(x)$. Its width is $\pi$. The temperature distribution $f(x,y)$ satisfies the Laplace equation $\nabla^2 f=0$. You can assume that the temperature at $y\rightarrow\infty$ is $0$.

My final result is $\sum_{n even} \frac{4n}{\pi (n^2-1)} sin(nx) e^{-ny}$

My procedure was this:

Solve Laplace equation with separation of variables and obtain $f=\sum_{n} B_n sin(nx)e^{-ny}$ This should be true because you need it to give zero at the sides.

If at $y=0$ , $f=cos(x)$ then I can use the function above to create a fourier sine series like:
$\sum_{n} B_n sin(nx)=cos(x)$

Where $B_n=\frac{2}{l}\int_{0}^{\pi}cos(x)sin(nx)dx=\frac{4n}{\pi(n^2-1)}$ for $n$ even.

Substituting that I get the final function I wrote above.

Now for some reason this is different from what some of my mates have been getting.

If I graph the function I obtain:

[image]

Which doesn't seem right to me. Note the function graphed above is different because of some constant values, but, if I write it correctly I still obtain this weirdness.

Comment: There is a problem with your boundary condition: it is not continuous at the corners. For instance your boundary condition is requiring $f(0,0)=0$ and $f(0,0)=1$ to have continuity. Hence you are not currently satisfying the lower boundary condition; indeed there is no hope of satisfying the lower boundary condition with your setup, because $\cos(x)$ is orthogonal to the entire system $\{ \sin(nx) \}_{n=1}^\infty$.

Comment: How can one satisfy that condition then? It seems impossible to satisfy.

Comment: There is no way to make a strong solution to your equation with those boundary conditions. You would need to pass to a weak solution to even define a sensible notion of solution.

Comment: Hmm. But in other problems such as solving the laplace equation in a cylindrical body, where you get Fourier-Bessel series, you can have a temperature at the bottom and also that the temperatures give 0 at the rim. Why would this work here?

Comment: Whatever notion of solution you have with a discontinuous boundary condition, it isn't strong, because the resulting function isn't continuous up to the boundary.

Comment: Well these problems arise in my book on mathematical physics. It might be possible that the temperature is treated as discontinuous at the border because it changes to fast I guess. Why would these problems appear in my mathematical physics book?

Comment: Also , what you said about orthogonality doesn't really matter (I believe) because were integrating from 0 to $\pi$ not 0 to $2\pi$ where each integral would've vanished.

Comment: The function I obtained was correct. The problem was in the scale. See the graphs I've posted below, they are quite nice :D

Comment: You're right that I missed the lack of a 2. I am still skeptical as to the sense in which your construction is a solution. It definitely does not work pointwise.

Answer (score 0):

The function is correct. See the graph I've obtained. The problem was in the scale.

[image]

[image]